# eclipse jboss 7.1 plugin

Tags: eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin

I used the http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/indigo/ for new updates but I still cannot find jboss 7.0 in eclipse under window->preferences-->server-->runtime enviroment. I downloaded eclipse Indigo SR2.

Answer (score 3):

The plugin is only to manage JBoss runtime. Plugin does not install JBoss AS 7 itself. You can easily download the app server and [setup the runtime](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Starting+JBoss+AS+from+Eclipse+with+JBoss+Tools).